# Net total of a quote line item is changing upon calculation

Tags: quote, pricebook, cpq, product, steelbrick

I have a product set to $5000. The product option is set to $5000. When the product is added to the bundle and it is saved, it jumps to $9000. The standard price of the product is set to 5000, it is set to 5000 in the custom price book, there are no price rules on the bundle pertaining to this product.
However, the List unit price and the net unit price are both 9000 while the original price is 5000 on the quote line. Does anybody have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

In case of subscription products the price may increase or decrease on Quoteline on the basis of Subscription term can you check the subscription type and term of the Quoteline and Quote if they are more than one year, you can identify the term through start and end date of Quote also.